# How to drag a navigation controller into a tab bar controller within a storyboard?

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

With xibs if you wanted to combine a navigation controller and tab bar controller you could just drag n drop the navigation controller into the tab bar controller.

However this is not possible now with storyboards (in Xcode 5). Is there some other way of doing it graphically?

Note I don't want the navigation controller to cause a tab to appear in the tab bar controller as will happen if you ctrl drag from the tab bar controller to the nag controller. I want a navigation bar and tab bar combined in one view.

There's dozens and dozens of tutorials for this out there, but they are all using nibs or old versions of storyboards/xcode, and when I try to do it for Xcode 5 it isn't possible. I was wondering if there's some new trick to get the same behavior as was previously possible.

Answer (score 0):

In a storyboard, you can control-drag or right-click drag from the `UITabBarController` to the `UINavigationController` to add it as one of the view controllers for the tab bar.

Comment: If you do that then a tab will appear for the navigation view controller. I don't  want that, I want a navigation bar and tab bar in the main view. Sorry, edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Read my answer. It says to drag from the tab bar controller to the navigation controller, NOT from the navigation controller to the tab bar controller. It will work if you do it in the right direction.

Comment: No you read my reply. Have you even tried what you are suggesting? It does not work.

Comment: I just tried this, it takes literally 30 seconds to create a new project and try it out. If you Ctrl-drag from a TBC to a NV and choose a segue of type relationship then IB creates a new additional tab in the TB for the NVC. And choosing one of the other segue types would not be applicable.

Comment: You could maybe use this approach and thus drag n drop to N number of NVCs depending upon how many views/tabs you want to have. However a consequence of this would be there would be N navigation controllers and N navigation bars rather than one, which doesn't seem good. I don't know how you can get down to one navigation controller as you used to with older versions of IB, so am curious.